# "leave a mark in" VS "leave an imprint in"

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> 1. Our efforts to tackle the crisis will **leave an imprint in** the annals of history.
> 2. Our efforts to tackle the crisis will **leave a mark in** the annals of history.

I thought of two ways to express the what we did in the crisis would go down in histroy. I am wondering whether they are both suitable and exchangable. Is there another way to say this?

Answer (score 1):

Both have the same meaning but *leave a footprint* implies that it is more visible. A footprint is big and more visible than a mark.

Comment: The problem with ***footprint*** here is that it's a glaring (to me, at least) [mixed metaphor](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mixed-metaphor), since ***annals*** are *[written] **historical records*** (conceptually, on paper, papyrus, clay tablets,...). Logically therefore, one might want to consider *...leave a **fingerprint** in the annals of history* - but of course nobody ever says that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't why I put the word footprint here. Orgianlly, I only wanted to compare "imprint" and "mark". Would the word "mark" be the best choice then?

Comment: I can't say exactly why, but my feeling is we don't normally use any variant of ***leave [noun]** in the annals of history*. Maybe precisely *because* there's no obvious front-runner noun. What I'm accustomed to is the more straightforward [*will **go down** in the annals of history*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will+go+down+in+the+annals+of+history%22) (with 1870 hits in Google Books).